# Sql Cleanse to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am struggling with the solution to a query and any help would be greatly appreciated, I end up tying myself In knots with temptables and I'm sure there must be an easier way.

I have a database currently producing the below results - this is as it comes with no joins or production prior.

```
Acc No      |  prod No  | Product Type | product Cost 
12345678           1               Red Toy              £100
12345678           2               Blue Toy             £150
12345678           3               White Toy           £300
12398654           1               White Toy           £300
12398765           1               Red Toy              £100
```

I only want one row per account number but don't want to lose the information. I would also like some sums. The below should hopefully show what I mean though there would be more columns:

```
 Acc No | Prod total | cost | Prod1type | Prod1cost |prod2typ
12345678         3      £550      Red Toy        £100      BlueToy
12398654         1      £300    White Toy       £300        Null
```

I hope this explains it. I'm aware I would end up with many more columns but it would make my life so much easier.

Any help would be hugely appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What happened to account 12398765?  Your question doesn't mention any filtering.

Comment: Sorry Gordon I just left it off , it would be a similar result to the 12398654 result

Comment: @LukeRedwood how about White Toy for 12345678 ?

Comment: That would be the next column, so every distinct product type would have a new column, as would it's price and type.

Answer (score 0):

With out considering adding `ProdType` you could use this query.
Assume also there is only 1 product per line in table.

```
select acc_no, count(*) as prod_total, sum(cost) as total_cost
from table
group by acc_no
order by acc_no asc
```

to get all `ProdType` for a coresponding acc_no you could use

```
select distinct prodtype
from table
where acc_no='exact_number'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure that works in terms of the result I want but i will try it on Monday. In excel you could do a simple vlookup and match the account number and bring the value from a row based on the product code. It's a 2 minute job but I can't use excel as it needs to be a package on ssis

Comment: What I provided should work. But you got results in 2 steps and you asked in just one. I'm not expert in `mssql` but assume you could also get whatever custom `select` you wanted. Any way the base of result are the above 2 queries. Just checked when time and let me know the feed-back. Maybe i will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple case statements to get your expected output.

Create sample data:

```
select 12345678 as Accno , 1 as prodno, 'Red Toy'   as Producttype , 100 as Cost into #temp union all 
select 12345678 as Accno , 2 as prodno, 'Blue Toy'  as Producttype , 150 as Cost  union all 
select 12345678 as Accno , 3 as prodno, 'White Toy' as Producttype , 300 as Cost  union all 
select 12398654 as Accno , 1 as prodno, 'White Toy' as Producttype , 300 as Cost  union all 
select 12398765 as Accno , 1 as prodno, 'Red Toy'   as Producttype , 100 as Cost
```

Query:

```
   select  accno, count(distinct prodno) Prodtotal, sum(cost) totalCost, max(case when prodno = 1 then Producttype end ) Product1type, 
sum (case when prodno = 1 then cost end) Product1cost, max(case when prodno = 2 then Producttype end ) Product2type, 
sum (case when prodno = 2 then cost end) Product2cost,max(case when prodno = 3 then Producttype end ) Product3type, 
sum (case when prodno = 3 then cost end) Product3cost  from #temp 
group by accno
```

Output:

Formatting might be little bit different, but I assume this is your expected output.

```
     accno  Prodtotal   totalCost   Product1type    Product1cost    Product2type    Product2cost    Product3type    Product3cost
12345678    3            550         Red Toy         100              Blue Toy    150   White Toy   300
12398654    1            300    White Toy            300               NULL       NULL  NULL    NULL
12398765    1            100    Red Toy              100               NULL NULL    NULL    NULL
```